# All graphs with maximum degree $\ge\frac{|V(G)|}{2}$ is Class 1

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, coloring, matching-theory

Are all even order graphs with maximum degree $\ge\frac{|V(G)|}{2}$ is Class 1(edge-colorable(chromatic index) with $\Delta(G)$ colors, where $\Delta(G)$ is maximun degree)? Here, $|V(G)|$ denotes the number of vertices in the graph.

I think yes, because, by Erdos-Posa theorem on the number of maximal disjoint circuits in a graph, we have that any graph has a matching of size at least $min(\Delta(G), \frac{|V(G)|}{2})$. Now, consider a regular graph of degree $\Delta(G)$. Then, by the Erdós-Pósa theorem, it will have a perfect matching(as $\Delta(G)\ge\frac{|V(G)|}{2})$, in fact, $\Delta$ perfect matchings(I think), and thus, should be 1-factorizable, that is must be Class 1. Thus, any graph with maximum degree at least $\Delta(G)$ should be Class 1. Any hints. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could define/explain Class 1...

Comment: @Mike Class 1 graphs are those graphs that are edge colorable(chromatic index) with $\delta(G)$ colors

Comment: @MariaMazur no, here, I am speaking of edge coloring, whereas your question speaks of edge connectivity

Comment: As far as I know, the maximum degree of a graph $G$ is denoted by $\Delta(G)$, whereas $\delta(G)$ denotes the minimum degree.

Comment: @AlexRavsky yes, that is the usual notation, but $\delta(G)=\Delta(G)$ for regular graphs, so i used them interchangably

Comment: So the graph $G$ in your question is regular?

Comment: @AlexRavsky no my intention was all graphs, not just regular. Slightly modified the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Start with a complete graph on $n-1$ vertices ($n$ even), and then subdivide one edge by adding a new vertex $v$ to make a graph on $n$ vertices. This graph has $(n-1)(n-2)/2+1=\frac{n^2-3n+4}{2}$ edges, and maximum degree $n-2$. Now colour as many edges as you can with $n-2$ colours. Since only two edges meet $v$, only two colour classes can contain $n/2$ edges, and the other classes contain at most $(n-2)/2$ edges each. So there are at most $n+(n-4)(n-2)/2=\frac{n^2-4n+8}{2}$ edges coloured, which is not enough if $n\geq 6$.

For *regular* graphs this is essentially the $1$-factorisation conjecture, which is known to be true for sufficiently large $n$ by a result of Csaba, Kühn, Lo, Osthus and Treglown. I don't know how large $n$ has to be for the proof to work, but probably very large; I believe it's still unknown whether it's true for all $n$.

Comment: but the conjecture is surely true for even vertex transitive graphs, as a 1-factor can always be found; and yes, for sufficiently large $n$ it is true by your quoted paper.